# Posrgresql: Need query to check if last record for a group of two columns is older than 30 mins or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic, having-clause

Below is what I have written:

```
select column1, column2 
where time::time between "07:00:00: and "17:00:00: and time - now() > "-00:30:00" 
group by column1, column2;
```

If I run this query every 30 mins, will it fetch me the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `having` clause:

```
select col1, col1
from mytable 
group by col1, col2
having max(time) >= now() - interval '30 minutes'
```

This returns all `(col1, col2)` tuples whose latest `time` is less than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: I think this will fetch me the records inserted in last 30 mins (for the groups col1, clo2). What my requirements was, I needed the records that are order than 30 mins. Lets say, current time is 9:30 AM, so I want all those groups of col1, col2 which are having max(time) 9:00 AM or less

Comment: @Abhishek: ok, so just change `>=` to `<`.